# optimizing conditions for speed

Tags: python, optimization

example code:

```
e = [[1,2,3,4],[0,...,10000],[4,5,6,7]]
for n in range(0,1000000):
  if n in e[0] and n in e[1] and n in e[2]:
    yield n
```

I'm trying to optimize for speed to avoid e[1] lookup for every iteration if i can find out before that e[1] == range. Same goes for e[0] == range or e[2] == range

let me clarify this a bit more..im trying to write crontab [http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205) parser in python.

Format for crontab is * * * * *

where first field is minutes range(0,60), second hours range(0,23), third days of month range(1,32), 4th month range(1,13), 5th day of week range(0,8)

when every field is matched something happens, 
i.e. for every day at 5,30 am format is

30 5 * * *

now simplest solution is to iterate through lower,upper boundary with increment of 60 seconds, since smallest increment is 1 minute. and replace * with full range, matched fields with single number enclosed in list.

simplest algorithm is

```
for ts in range(startts,endts,60): 
  now = time.localtime(ts)
  if now.tm_min in [5,] and now.tm_hour in [30,] and now.tm_mon in range(0,13) ... etc:
    yield now
```

since some of those fields are sometimes * list lookup is not needed, and im trying to figure out way to dynamically generate conditions based on '*'

Comment: related (if the input can be specified as intervals): [Fast interval intersection methodologies](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/99/fast-interval-intersection-methodologies)

Comment: Are these intervals of numbers really complete (no integers missing between top and bottom of interval)? If so, why not just check that `n` is between the top and the bottom - e[0][0] <= n <= e[0][1] for instance? Sets work great for this too, but I'm not fully sure what your end use will be so I thought that I'd throw that out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want to find all elements that are common to all three lists. This is essentially the same as finding the intersection of the sets represented by the lists. In Python we can simply use `set` and find the intersection.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

def get_values(lst):
    sets=map(set,lst)
    common=reduce(lambda x,y:x.intersection(y),sets,set(lst[0]))
    for value in common:
        yield value
if __name__=='__main__':
    e = [[1,2,3,4],range(10000),[4,5,6,7]]  
    for common_item in get_values(e):
        print common_item
```

Comment: Using sets is a sensible approach, but your example code isn't easily read (I've never been much of a fan of lambda)

Comment: @Jon Cage: Lambda seemed the most natural way to me in this particular case.

Comment: `get_values = lambda lst: reduce(set.intersection, lst, lst and set(lst[0]))`

Comment: First, your solution does not guarantee that the numbers are yielded in ascending order (though they appearantly are in cpython), since set is an _unordered_ collection. Use `for value in sorted(list(common))` to force ascending order. Second, the initializer argument `set(lst[0])` to `reduce` is not needed, and you may (or may not) want to use `x & y` instead of `x.intersection(y)`. Third, you should have a look at what the [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says about whitespace.

Comment: @lazyr: Thanks for your comments. 1)The way I understood it, the OP did not actually ask for the answer to be sorted. As you say, it is trivial to make it sorted. 2) I know, but I thought this form might be more understandable to the OP (explicitly using `intersect` because `&` might seem cryptic, and having an explicit initial value in reduce).

Comment: @lazyr: As for 3), The Python Style guide is a good guideline, but its just that: a guideline not a hard and fast rule. I am not religious about such matters. And this is not a large project. IMHO whatever conveys the idea of the solution in an understandable and succinct manner is best for SO. This is subjective and your idea of may differ.

Answer (score 0):

```
if n==4:
```

will do it. At least in your example.

Perhaps you should tell us what you're actually trying to do? Are the ranges always contiguous? What exactly are the constraints you're working under?

Comment: Im trying to write crontab parser that has * * * * * fields and if some of fields are * they shouldnt be matched in iteration..

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
e = [[1,2,3,4],[0,...,10000],[4,5,6,7]]
for n in e[0]:
  if and n in e[2] and n in e[1]:
    yield n
```

It will only check the values which exist in e[0]. If the numbers of elements are different in each sub-list, you could add one further generic optimisation which checks them in order of the size of lists so you check against the smallest list first (I did that by hand in this case, but you get the idea).